# Html Agility Pack Tables and rowspan

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Asset: 123499</td>
        <td>Unit 3A<br /></td>
        <td>12/7/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tdcolspan=3>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Asset: 123456</td>
        <td>Unit 5</td>
        <td>12/7/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>Asset: 123457</td>
        <td>Unit 8</td>
        <td>12/7/2013</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Unit 10</td>
        <td>12/7/2013</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to parse out the data. In most cases, each asset has a single unit, so it is easy to get the data, but in some cases, an asset has multiple units, so I end up with a rowspan for the asset number and then repeating information on the next row.

The last two rows of the table above are an example. I can't figure out how to compress the rowspan rows so that I get an asset number for each row and the individual unit information. There are also some white space rows that use a colspan and contain no data.

I would like to exclude them from the rows I am dealing with, but I am not sure how to do that either.
below is the code I am currently using:

```
HtmlNode tableDirty = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Last();
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tableDirty.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach (HtmlNode t in rows)
{
    HtmlNodeCollection cols = t.SelectNodes(".//td");
    int assetNumber;
    if (Int32.TryParse(cols[2].InnerHtml, out assetNumber))
    {
        tableData.Add(new TableData
        {
            AssetId = cols[0].InnerHtml,
            Unit = cols[1].InnerHtml,)
        });
    }
}
```